# How to safely remove Windows 8 after installation

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-8-preview

Recently I've installed Windows 8 alongside Windows 7. Now I want to remove Windows 8. How do I remove Windows 8 in a safe way?

Comment: okay why downgraded? can any one tell me how to remove?

Comment: Your question has already been answered but it's not what you want to hear

Answer (score 7):

Windows 8 cannot be uninstallled. You will need to reinstall Windows 7 from scratch

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516)

Comment: If you installed it alongside win7, like the question says, it's as easy as deleting the win8 partition and fixing the MBR.

Comment: Which part, exactly, of that link were you attempting to highlight?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your precise configuration.  If you have a dual-boot that would be easy, boot into Windows 7 and delete the Windows 8 partition.

If there is data on the Windows 8 partition, then how about a backup, reformat, restore just the data?

If Windows 7 and Windows 8 are on the same partition, that could be tricky.

Here are more ideas along the lines of redefining the [uninstall Windows 8 problem](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-uninstall.htm) until you come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what [Microsoft said](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:NDHv0B2GudUJ:windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-8/download+) about Windows 8 uninstallation :

> "If you decide to go back to your previous operating system, you'll need to reinstall it from the recovery or installation media that came with your PC, which is typically DVD media.
>
> "If you don’t have recovery media, you might be able to create it from a recovery partition on your PC using software provided by your PC manufacturer. Check the support section of your PC manufacturer's website for more information. After you install Windows 8, you won’t be able to use the recovery partition on your PC to go back to your previous version of Windows."

Answer (score 0):

You're dualbooting, so there's really two parts to this. I'd note this is not a risk free process, so having a backup is a great idea.

Firstly replacing your windows 8 bootloader with the windows 7 bootloader. Boot into windows 7, install easybcd and use that. In this case you want the BCD deployment option [image]

You will also want to delete the windows 8 entry, but lets do that later.

Reboot, check if you have the windows 7 bootloader. Boot into windows 7. Delete the windows 8 entry, format the windows 8 disk. If desired, resize the partitions with a suitable tool, and thats about it.